# ui-router named views with route and url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

just a quick question. Can named views in the ui-router for angular have routes and an url? And if so, how can I activate them?
I searched through the wiki, but can't find any info on that.
What I want is a app with three different child routes so only one can be active at a time, but they're supposed to be in different views, so I can nicely animate between them with an accordion effect.
Any help there?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here's some code of my routing so far:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        //templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        //controller: 'MainController',
        //controllerAs: 'main',
        views: {
          '' : {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'main'
          },
          'contact': {
            templateUrl: 'app/contact/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController',
            controllerAs: 'contact'
          },
          'profile': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            controllerAs: 'profile'
          },
          'works': {
            templateUrl: 'app/works/works.html',
            controller: 'WorksController',
            controllerAs: 'works'
          }
        }
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
```

Comment: could you add code..what you have tried so far?

Comment: I added my current routing with the try for the named routes...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just creating different states for each view. There's no reason you can't animate smoothly between different states.

So:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
    })      
  .state('home.contact', {          
        templateUrl: 'app/contact/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactController',
        controllerAs: 'contact'
      })
  .state('home.profile', {
        templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileController',
        controllerAs: 'profile'
        params: {
            "user" : {}
        }
      })
  .state('home.works', {
        templateUrl: 'app/works/works.html',
        controller: 'WorksController',
        controllerAs: 'works'
      })
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

}

In your ui-sref links, you can pass data to those views using parameters, like this: `<a ui-sref="home.profile({user: contact.user})` along with the 'params' section in the state definition as I've included above.

Comment: Hmm I had it like that before but I'm not sure how to animate the states then. Design-wise I want to have content appear on different areas of the page on the different states

Comment: The way I've done it is to just have animation properties on the html within each template. If you're going from `home.contact` to `home.profile` then yes, it will replace the whole ui-view with new template content. If you want to use a child ui-view, then use `home.contact.profile` to set contact as the parent view.

Answer (score -4):

Routing is serverside so if you call any address your serverside routing needs to launch proper html or javascripts which will let you render what you want.

For more accurate answer please respond with more details: what is your serverside engine, which version of angular you use etc.

Comment: ui-router is an Angular client-side routing library.